# Unable to get single dropdown for each row in autocomplete in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system

Component HTML:

```
<div class="slds-box">
         <table class="slds-table PoTable slds-max-medium-table_stacked" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-color:#000;">
            <tr class="tableheader">
               <th scope="col">
                  <div class="center">Product Name</div>
               </th>
               <th scope="col">
                  <div class="center">Serial No</div>
               </th>
            </tr>
           <aura:iteration items="{!v.inventorySerialNoLst}" var="inv" indexVar="invIndex">
               <tr class="slds-hint-parent cOrderOliTable">
                  <td>
                     <div class="center"> {!inv.Product__r.Name}</div>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <div class="center">
                        <div class="slds-form-element">
                           <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="combobox-id-21"
                              style="{! empty(v.label) ? 'display:hidden;' : 'display:block;'}">{!v.label}</label>
                           <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                              <div class="slds-combobox_container">
                                 <div class="{! v.openDropDown ? 'slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click slds-is-open' : 'slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click'}"
                                    aria-expanded="true" aria-haspopup="listbox" role="combobox">
                                    <div class="slds-combobox__form-element slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_right" role="none">
                                       <input type="text"
                                          class="slds-input slds-combobox__input slds-has-focus slds-combobox__input-value"
                                          id="combobox-id-21" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="listbox-id-11"
                                          autoComplete="off" onkeyup="{!c.searchHandler}" role="textbox" placeholder="Search..."
                                          value="{!inv.inputValue}" />
                                       <aura:if isTrue="{! empty(v.selectedOption)}">
                                          <span
                                             class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-search slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right">
                                             <lightning:icon iconName="utility:search" size="x-small" />
                                          </span>
                                          <aura:set attribute="else">
                                             <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right"
                                                title="Clear the text input" onclick="{!c.clearOption}">
                                                <lightning:icon iconName="utility:clear" size="x-small" />
                                             </button>
                                          </aura:set>
                                       </aura:if>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="listbox-id-11" class="slds-dropdown slds-dropdown_length-5 slds-dropdown_fluid"
                                       role="listbox">
                                       <ul class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical" role="presentation">
                                          <aura:iteration items="{!v.results}" var="result" indexVar="proIndex">
                                             <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item" 
                                                
                                                 data-record="{!'serial'+result.Serial_Number__c+'_'+proIndex}" onclick="{!c.optionClickHandler}">
                                                <div id="{!result.id}"
                                                   class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media_small"
                                                   role="option">
                                                   <span class="slds-media__figure slds-listbox__option-icon"></span>
                                                   <span class="slds-media__body">
                                                   <span class="slds-truncate" title="All Opportunities">
                                                   <span>{!result.Serial_Number__c}</span>
                                                   </span>
                                                   </span>
                                                </div>
                                             </li>
                                          </aura:iteration>
                                       </ul>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </aura:iteration>
         </table>
      </div>
```

Controller JS:

```
({
    
    doInit : function (component, event, helper) {
        
        var productId = component.get('v.productId');
        //console.log('=9==',JSON.stringify(productId));
        
    },
    searchHandler : function (component, event, helper) {
        const searchString = event.target.value;
        if (searchString.length >= 3) {
            //Ensure that not many function execution happens if user keeps typing
            if (component.get("v.inputSearchFunction")) {
                clearTimeout(component.get("v.inputSearchFunction"));
            }

            var inputTimer = setTimeout($A.getCallback(function () {
                helper.searchRecords(component, searchString);
            }), 1000);
            component.set("v.inputSearchFunction", inputTimer);
        } else{
            component.set("v.results", []);
            component.set("v.openDropDown", false);
        }
    },

    optionClickHandler : function (component, event, helper) {
        //var prodData = event.target.dataset.caseid;
        var selectedItem = event.currentTarget;
        var bothindexes= selectedItem.dataset.record.replace("serial","").split("_");
        var serialNo = bothindexes[0];
        var serialNoIndex=bothindexes[1];
         console.log('--prodData--',serialNo);
        console.log('--eventIndex--',serialNoIndex);
        var inventorySerialNoLst = component.get("v.inventorySerialNoLst");
        inventorySerialNoLst[serialNoIndex].inputValue=serialNo;
        console.log('==37=='+JSON.stringify(inventorySerialNoLst));
        component.set("v.inventorySerialNoLst", inventorySerialNoLst);
        component.set("v.openDropDown", false);
        component.set("v.selectedOption", inventorySerialNoLst[serialNoIndex].inputValue); 
    },

    clearOption : function (component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.results", []);
        component.set("v.openDropDown", false);
        component.set("v.inputValue", "");
        component.set("v.selectedOption", "");
    },
})
```

Helper JS:

```
({
    searchRecords : function(component, searchString) {
        
        var productId = component.get('v.productId');
        console.log('=9==',JSON.stringify(productId));
        var action = component.get("c.getSerialNo");
        action.setParams({
            "productId" : productId,
            "searchString" : searchString
        });
        action.setCallback(this,function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                const serverResult = response.getReturnValue();
                component.set('v.results',serverResult);
                console.log('==serverResult==',JSON.stringify(serverResult));
                const results = [];
                if(serverResult.length>0){
                    component.set("v.openDropDown", true);
                }
            } else{
                var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                if(toastEvent){
                    toastEvent.setParams({
                        "title": "ERROR",
                        "type": "error",
                        "message": "Something went wrong!! Check server logs!!"
                    });
                    toastEvent.fire();
                }
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

[image]

I am trying to implement autocomplete in aura iteration in lightning component. Whenever I am searching the data on specific row, the dropdown for lightning component for autocomplete comes for all the remaining rows. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: While asking questions, (when applicable) try to provide some screenshots that would make it easier to understand the problem and explain a bit on any troubleshooting you have already done. In your case looks like the problem may be in the JS code (most likely because the auto complete might be provided by the event handler wired in the html element) and hence, without the JS code, it would be nearly impossible for anybody to help you out. My suggestion for you is to improve this question.

Comment: Thanks @arut for your suggestion.Now I have attached the screenshots and the controller and helper js.I am able to get the data in my autocomplete box as you can see on screenshot But when I am searching data on first autocomplete box the dropdown is appearing for both the rows.

Comment: It is happening because you are using a single variable to control the open/close of the drop down via attrubute`openDropDown`. The ideal way to do it would be to use create a component for type ahead and then use it, that way the state management would work correctly because it would be scoped. You may also utilize existing typeahead component available, built by others for this.

Comment: Do I need to create another component for autocomplete problem.

Comment: Yes, please do that.

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem.